# Is there a word that describes "ranking up a position"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a good word to describe "ranking up a position"?

For example, say a programmer: A junior programmer _____s into a senior programmer....

*Ranks up* doesn't sound that good, and I'm looking for a single word (if any exists).

Comment: That's known as "a promotion".

Comment: If he works for a gaming company, you might say he "levels up". :)

Comment: 'Develops' 'Elevates to the level of' 'Ascends to the rank of'...
If you have a strange view of programmers, 'metamorphoses' is a nice turn of phrase (I'm a programmer, so I can say that ;) ).

Comment: Why no one write answer for question? No answer, john2546 no can mark good answer. No answer, question look like no answer when there is answer. This question and answer website, no question and comment website. **john2546**, if you like one or more of the suggestions in the comments, you are allowed to answer your own question, below, and then mark the answer as the best answer.

Comment: @HunterHogan - We're all too lazy to write actual answers.  Plus, you write an answer and folks expect some sort of reference, and, again, we're lazy.

Comment: (I often tell a newbie, if he sees a comment he thinks is the answer, to just go ahead and answer the question himself, and then accept it after the waiting period expires.  I don't need the points.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going up the ranks in a professional (workplace) environment is typically known as a ***promotion***.

> Andy got promoted to senior management yesterday.
>
> I'm hoping to get promoted to vice president soon.

However a ***promotion*** is usually used to show advancement in a specific job or workplace. There are other terms which imply more general career advancements through one's professional career.
A junior programmer having achieved 5 years of experience is usually ***ranked up*** or ***receives the title*** of senior programmer. This title/rank is independent of a specific position at a company which is why you see many job postings looking to hire a *senior programmer* or *senior developer* (implying the title *senior* can be independent of a current job title at a specific company).

**Side Note:** In the field of computer science there are also other *ranks* that can *only* be achieved through experience. For example when a company is looking for a *Software Architect* they are not trying to find people who majored in software architecture (such a major rarely exists). What they are looking for (usually) is a software engineer with 10+ years of experience. In short, there are certain titles which are not entry-level (meaning you can not earn a degree and automatically earn that title) which don't necessarily start with *senior* or *junior* but are achieved through a similar process.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a word to accompany the act of moving into the more senior position, then the already-suggested *promotion* is quite adequate.

If, however, you are looking for a word that describes the *process* of gaining the skills and experience, then [***mature***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mature) might be a better word:

> : to become fully developed in the body and mind
>   : to continue developing to a desired level
>   <sub>source: www.m-w.com/dictionary/mature</sub>

(Alternatively, as that definition suggests, ***develop*** could also be suitable.)